# return validation errors as an array and change to json

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I am trying to return my validation errors to angular but I can't figure out how to return them in the format array('field under validation' => 'error message').  This exact array is held in errors->messages() but it is a protected property.

here is my code

validator.php

```
<?php namespace TrainerCompare\Services\Validation;

use Validator as V;

/**
*
*/
abstract class Validator 
{
    protected $errors;

    public function validate($data)
    {
        $validator = V::make($data, static::$rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->errors = $validator->messages();

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function errors()
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

controller

```
<?php

use TrainerCompare\Services\Validation\ProgramValidator;

class ProgramsController extends BaseController
{
    protected $program;
    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(Program $program, ProgramValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->program = $program;
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }
/**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();

        $v = $this->validator->validate($input);

        if ($v == true) {
            //$this->program->create($input);

            return Response::json(
                array('success' => true)
            );
        } else {

            $errors = $this->validator->errors();

            return Response::json(
                array('errors' => $errors)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

this returns the json

```
{"errors":{}}
```

if I change the controller to

```
$errors = $this->calidator->errors()->all();
```

this is returned

```
{"errors":["The title field is required.","The focus field is required.","The desc field is required."]}
```

what I really want returned is

```
{"errors":[title: "The title field is required.",focus: "The focus field is required.",desc: "The desc field is required."]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Validator errors in Laravel return a [`MessageBag`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.MessageBag.html) object, which has many useful methods you may want to look over.

It sounds like what you want is the `toArray` method, and you can use it like so in your controller.

Replace the following code that you have in your controller;

```
$errors = $this->validator->errors();

return Response::json(
    array('errors' => $errors)
);
```

With;

```
$errors = $this->validator->errors()->toArray();

return Response::json(
    array('errors' => $errors)
);
```

Or, depending how how you're using it with Angular, you can return the object directly, using the `toJson` method.

```
return $this->validator->errors()->toJson();
```